# Change sign using bitwise operators

Tags: performance, int, bit-manipulation

How to change the sign of int using bitwise operators? Obviously we can use `x*=-1` or `x/=-1`. Is there any fastest way of doing this?

I did a small test as below. Just for curiosity...

```
public class ChangeSign {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 198347;
        int LOOP = 1000000;
        int y;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            y = (~x) + 1;
        }
        long mid1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            y = -x;
        }
        long mid2 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            y = x * -1;
        }
        long mid3 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            y = x / -1;
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(mid1 - start);
        System.out.println(mid2 - mid1);
        System.out.println(mid3 - mid2);
        System.out.println(end - mid3);
    }
}
```

Output is almost similar to :

```
2200211
835772
1255797
4651923
```

Comment: You could implement an adder and call it 32 times. :P

Comment: Most ISAs (including x86) have a dedicated integer negation instruction. It's not gonna get any faster than that.

Comment: Retagged this considering most discussion here is not java-specific, though applicable to java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The speed difference between non-floating point (e.g. int math) addition/multiplication and bitwise operations is less than negligible on almost all machines.

There is no general way to turn an n-bit signed integer into its negative equivalent using only bitwise operations, as the negation operation looks like `x = (~x) + 1`, which requires one addition. However, assuming the signed integer is 32 bit you can probably write a bitwise equation to do this calculation. **Note**: do not do this.

The most common, readable way to negate a number is `x = -x`.

Comment: `x = -x` Simple, but didn't have that idea. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Java uses Complement Two representation. In order to change a sign, it means you must do a bitwise negation (it would be equivalent to xor with FFFF) and add 1.

```
x = ~x + 1;
```

I am almost sure that `-x` is, if anything, faster than that.

Comment: `x ^ 0xFFFFFFFF` is logically the same as `~x`, but it requires 1 extra operation, specifically `load 0xFFFFFFFF`. Usually bitwise negation is accomplished with a bitwise negation operator.

Comment: Didn't knew of the `~` operator, it has been too long since I have done anything other than `|` or `&.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using high level language

Questions like these are popular in interviews and competitive programming world .

I landed here researching more solution for negation of a number without using - or + operator .

For this :

1. complement a number using ~ operator
2. Then add 1 to the number obtained in step 1 using Half adder logic :

   ```
   int addNumbers(int x, int y) { 
               if(y==0) return x; // carry is 0 return 
               addNumbers(x^y,(x&y)<<1); }
   ```

Here x^y performs addition of bits and x&y handles carry operation

Comment: aw3some.  Eli ??

Comment: @user2290820 sorry but what Eli means ? xD

Comment: `return` should not be in the comment.